# Number of different values assoicated with a key in a list of dicts

Tags: python, dictionary

Given a list of dictionaries ( each of which have same keys), I want total number of different values with which a given key is associated

`$ li = [{1:2,2:3},{1:2,2:4}] $` the expected output is {1:1,2:2}

I came up with the following piece of code...Is there a better way of doing this ?

```
      counts = {} 
      values = {}
      for i in li:  
         for key,item in i.items():
             try:
                 if item in values[key]:
                    continue
             except KeyError:
                 else:
                    try:
                       counts[key] += 1
                    except KeyError:
                       counts[key] = 1
                    try:
                       values[key].append(item)
                    except KeyError:
                       values[key] = [item]
```

Comment: your code isn't valid. the try..except and if..else clauses are mixed up.

Comment: Remember to accept an answer if one works well for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this is probably more direct:

```
from collections import defaultdict

counts = defaultdict(set)

for mydict in li:
  for k, v in mydict.items():
    counts[k].add(v)
```

That takes care of the collecting / counting of the values.  To display them like you want them, this would get you there:

```
print dict((k, len(v)) for k, v in counts.items())
# prints {1: 1, 2: 2}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is yet another alternative:

```
from collections import defaultdict

counts = defaultdict(int)
for k, v in set(pair for d in li for pair in d.items()):
    counts[k] += 1
```

And the result:

```
>>> counts
defaultdict(<type 'int'>, {1: 1, 2: 2})
```

Answer (score 0):

You could so something like this:

```
li = [{1:2,2:3},{1:2,2:4}]

def makesets(x, y):
  for k, v in x.iteritems():
    v.add(y[k])
  return x

distinctValues = reduce(makesets, li, dict((k, set()) for k in li[0].keys()))
counts = dict((k, len(v)) for k, v in distinctValues.iteritems())
print counts
```

When I run this it prints:

```
{1: 1, 2: 2}
```

which is the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

```
counts = {} 
values = {}

for i in li:  
  for key,item in i.items():
    if not (key in values.keys()):
      values[key] = set()
    values[key].add(item)

for key in values.keys():
  counts[key] = len(values[key])
```

Answer (score 0):

using flattening list in case dicts are not alway same length:

```
li=[{1: 2, 2: 3}, {1: 2, 2: 4}, {1: 3}]
dic={}
for i,j in [item for sublist in li for item in sublist.items()]:
    dic[i] = dic[i]+1 if i in dic else 1
```